# Why is 灸 pronounced jiu1?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

The pinyin of 灸 as in 针灸 (acupuncture) or 艾灸 (moxibustion) is clearly given as jiu3, as shown in, among others, [MDGB](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%89%BE%E7%81%B8) and [Zdic](http://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%89%BE%E7%81%B8).

The single character doesn't even have alternate pronunciations, only jiu3 [is listed](http://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%81%B8).

However in speech I've always heard it pronounced **jiu1** (example: https://youtu.be/RJFsJi7JvFI?t=10). In this other video though (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lJhs4vz4eI) it's pronounced as the dictionary suggests.

Is jiu1 a pronunciation of southern dialects? How did it come about?

Comment: Yes, it is a common mistake. Most of the people around me make the same mistake. I realized it is wrong just a year ago, and I live on the north bank of the Yantze River.

Comment: Both [普通话 (Mainland)](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%81%B8) and [國語 (Taiwan)](https://www.moedict.tw/%E7%81%B8) standards for Mandarin have jiǔ, corresponding to Middle Chinese 上聲. However, most southern Chinese topolects have readings with tones corresponding to Middle Chinese 去聲, e.g. Cantonese _gau3_, Hokkien _kiù_ (文) & _kù_ (白). [Both readings](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E7%81%B8) exist in Guangyun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but some references that might be helpful and are too long for the comments section.

---

This is clearly a phenomenon because the first note written on 灸 in《规范》says:

> 注意 ㊀不读jiū。

But, without much of an explanation it is hard to see why they mention it other than the obvious idea that it often gets mispronounced this way.

---

As for southern dialects《现代汉语方言音库 • 成都话音档》has the following entry:

> 灸
> tɕiəu⁵⁵

The tone is noted as:

> ⁵⁵

Which is clearly 阴平, the same as jiu1.

---

Looking through the tones on: [灸 | Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%81%B8) we also have:

A high flat tone:

> Hakka = /ki̯u⁵⁵/

and a middle flat tone:

> Cantonese = /kɐu̯³³/